# 403 Forbidden while accessing github repo

Tags: github, ssh, ssh-keygen

I have generated an ssh key using the following

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
```

I have also added the ssh key to my github settings.

However, when I try and clone, I get this error message

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/somepath/.git/
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://github.com/somelink.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

The same works from another laptop though

Comment: `fatal: HTTP request failed` are you sure you copied SSH url from the github?

Answer (score 0):

you can't authenticate to github with ssh keys using `https` urls. You need to use `ssh:` url [(docs)](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/)